# How to use cl2.hpp with AMD GPU and rocm

Tags: opencl, amd-gpu

I've been developing with OpenCL on my Laptop for a while now, but want to move to my more powerful desktop pc with an AMD GPU. I followed the breadcrumbs through APP SDK (which is apparently gone) through amdgpu-pro drivers (which completely crash my system) and landed on rocm. I can't install the drivers on my kernel, but the rocm-dev seems to work fine. Unfortunately I can't seem to be able to use Khronos' cl2.hpp anymore, as it doesn't seem tk link to any cl calls. I would like to still be able to work with the Intel CPU on my laptop without completely rewriting my code. Is it possible to easily integrate cl2.hpp into my rocm installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. I wasn't linking against the `libOpenCL.so` correctly. I am using **cmake** and set `OpenCL_LIBRARY` to the `amdgpu-pro` `lib` directory rather than the actual library file. Apparently `FIND (OpenCL)` doesn't work with the `/opt` paths rocm and amdgpu provide.